# Map enveloped response into a POJO

Tags: java, spring, http, pojo, envelope

I am trying to map the following response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
        "counts": {
            "media": 1320,
            "follows": 420,
            "followed_by": 3410
        }
}
```

into an object where I only want to retrieve the username, full_name, and id fields.

Ex: something like:

```
public class User{
    String id;
    String username;
    String full_name;

   // getters + setters

}
```

Is there a way of doing this without first having to store the data object into a Map?

Comment: What's wrong mapping the complete `json` to object and getting the fields you required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Jackson API. It should be simple:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(jsonString, User.class); //jsonString is your actual json string.
```

You might want to tweak your User class to match the JSON string. E.g. your user class needs to have a 'data' field as `List<Data> data;` where 'Data' is another POJO. You can add the "id", "userName", etc fields in the 'Data' pojo.

Comment: Furthermore, the Jackson library will also give you object mappers like for XML and CSV, if those are things you may need.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it by hand via, for example, regexp or utilize any of JSON libraries like Jackson, GSON etc.

Answer (score 0):

With GSON it's pretty simple. Say your json is stored in a `String jsonString` variable.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, YourObject.class);
```

Although I'm not sure what will happen, since your `jsonString` doesn't have a key called `User`. However, this should work if you first extract `data` from your `jsonString` and name your POJO `Data`.